# will an android service run code from the Xamarin Forms Project even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, service, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin Forms Project and i want to implement a service that will run signalr and will start with the phone boot.

right now i'm implementing other functionalities of the app, but will be great if the code that do the work in the service can be shared between android and iOS, if someone has done this before i'll appreciate any info that can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be achieved in android 8.0 or later, because it don’t allow register the service in the background, there are some limitations you could [refer to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80).

Here are some practical alternatives to an Android service:

- Schedule work to run in the background using the Android Job
  Scheduler or the Firebase Job Dispatcher
- Start the service in the foreground
- Use a high priority Firebase Cloud Message (FCM)
- Defer work for when the app comes into the foreground

Before android 8.0, you could define a broadcast receiver, then filter android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED ,if App filter it and start service in the background.

“will be great if the code that do the work in the service can be shared between android and iOS”

No, it cannot be achieved that in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Great answer, Thankyou, i did not know that with 8.0 an onwards i cannot use the broadcastreceiver, how do whatsapp work?

my service cannot rely on FCM, how can i start the service at boot on 8.0 then? lots of questions jajajaa

Comment: Maybe JobScheduler is a good choice, you could refer to this link to know more details:https://blog.xamarin.com/replacing-services-jobs-android-oreo-8-0/